# How could i determine the encryption and cipher of Wireless Network with Wireshark?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, encryption, wireshark

I am trying to understand the 802.11 Management and Data frames. I've get through many frames using wireshark and a captured .cap file but not able to find any suitable packet that could show me the encryption and cipher of a wireless network. Which frame would help me in determining so and how?

Comment: I think you are asking about packets. Can you clarify what do you mean by `encryption and cipher of Wireless Network` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPA and WPA2 aka 802.11i exchange a few 802.1X messages for authentication, see e.g. [here](https://is.muni.cz/el/1433/jaro2008/PV204/um/5184805/hakin9_wifi_EN.pdf?lang=en) for a nice summary and some details.

Note that these messages don't contain the keys themselves; you won't be able to decrypt WLAN frames with captured frames alone.

If you are just asking about capabilities, the beacon frame of an access point has fields that described the offered encryption modes and ciphers.